# iOS 8: Passing data from mainViewController to active other viewController

Tags: ios

I´m just beginning with iOS development so sorry for maybe newbee question but did not find any information on that.

I am writing a test app using estimote beacons. I´m getting the information within my `mainVewController` and pass them to another `viewController` if a button is pressed. Within this other `viewcontroller` (`detailViewController`) i present all the details from each beacon.

The update information from the beacons are still catched at the main `viewcontroller`. I want them to be passed to the active `detailViewController`.

There should be a method to identify the active view and pass data like in `prepareForSegue` but i cannot find such a method.

Comment: Why do i get negative rating for my question?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer on my own:

```
if self.presentedViewController is DetailViewController {

        var detailVC = self.presentedViewController as! DetailViewController
        detailVC.getExternalUpdateForBeacons()


    }
```